# how to do most effective slideshow with call=ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, slideshow, browser-cache, http-caching

I have seen few websites doing like this. Even though the page url is changed into new url and even the content(few parts of the page) is changed the webpage doesnt get reloaded. 
For example consider this webiste link http://www.indiatimes.com/entertainment/bollywood/srk-priyanka-deepika-farhan-get-stylish-at-an-awards-show-127716-2.html

when i click on the next button.. the url changes to ---*127716-3.html and the image changes where as the sidebar and menu etc(rest of the page) doesn't even reload. 
When i observed the http requests sent. It only asks for *****127716-3.html?call=ajax .This request only sends the image, caption of the image and the number of image in the slideshow. I searched for it but couldn't get anything relevant to this.

How is this whole thing done, what are the different technologies used and what should i learn to implement similar slideshow.  If possible someone can show me the code.

PS: i am no way related to the link i posted here.

Comment: Sounds like HTML5 history API.

Comment: doesnt look anything related to history api to me.